# Getting Started Node-React App Throwing Error in partner dashboard "This app can’t load due to an issue with browser cookies

Tags: node.js, next.js, shopify, koa, shopify-app

**Shopify Node React Nextjs App**, created using **shopify CLI** which runs perfectly while serving from localhost using Ngrok or LocalTunnel.

I have uploaded this to an Ubuntu instance on AWS, it compiled successfully.
But when I tried to access from shopify dashboard, it's throwing error.

This is just an hello world app, it should show Hello world , that's it.

**Error**
**"The app couldn’t be loaded
This app can’t load due to an issue with browser cookies. Try enabling cookies in your browser, switching to another browser
, or contacting the developer to get support."**

It has no issue in compilation, it compiled successfully, but when it tries to authenticate, redirecting couple of times and then throwing the above error in dashboard.

**App type:** Shopify Node React Next Koa-Auth