# Shopify Application: This app can’t load due to an issue with browser cookies

Tags: node.js, shopify, shopify-app

When generating an app via the `npm init @shopify/app@latest` when running `npm run dev` and installing the app on the Shopify store. The following error is presented `This app can’t load due to an issue with browser cookies. Try enabling cookies in your browser, [switching to another browser](https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-Apps/Some-Third-Party-Apps-may-not-be-accessible-on-Chrome-80-update/m-p/650220/thread-id/20503), or contacting the developer to get support.`

- `@shopify/shopify-app-remix` version: 1.1.0
- Node version: 18.6.1
- Operating system: Windows 11

### Expected behavior

The app should install correctly and display the demo page.

### Actual behavior

The app provides the detailed error

### Steps to reproduce the problem

1. Run `npm init @shopify/app@latest`
2. Run `npm start dev`
3. Install the application
4. Launch the application

Comment: Similar question asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69362273/getting-started-node-react-app-throwing-error-in-partner-dashboard-this-app-can with no answer. However, this question refers to deploying the app. The app is not working on localhost unlike this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The devs have provided a fix at https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-app-template-remix/issues/332

Running the following commands resolves the issue.

```
npm run config:link
npm run config:push
npm run dev
```

Answer (score 1):

1. npm run config:link
2. npm run config:push
3. npm run dev

this work for me

Comment: Welcome to SO! Although correct,  your answer came 8 days after the correct and already accepted as an answer, and it is identical to it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried installing with `npm init @shopify/app@latest` with `remix` as well, `npm run dev` with no issues after installation.

After running `npm run dev`, logged in my Google accounts and I am able to see Shopify Partners page.

Node version: 18.17.1

** During first initialisation it will ask you to press any key to open browser to login, please try to open in it non-incognito mode maybe?